# Installation PhalconPHP on CentOS

Tags: php, frameworks, installation, centos

Can you please tell how to install PhalconPHP on CentOS?

Comment: 1. This is off topic. 2. You can easily google this 3. Or get the info from the site 4. don't use bold text for questions

Comment: @John Conde,  1. No. 2. I have not found. 3. There's no such information. 4. Okay.

Comment: @user2103371 http://phalconphp.com/en/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo yum install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc 

sudo yum install git-core

git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git   

cd cphalcon/build   

sudo ./install
```

To fix "phpize: command not found"

Try: `yum -y install php-devel` and do `sudo ./install` again after that. Make sure you are still in the right directory.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/twkr4

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not good at Linux.

Comment: I believe CentOS uses yum so you need to do like: "sudo yum install gcc"  and "sudo yum install git-core" etc

Comment: "sudo yum install gcc" - ok, "git clone .." - no

Comment: @ Edward van Raak, http://prntscr.com/twlx0

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it?

Comment: Thank you to install, but not completely. http://prntscr.com/tyam6  The last line shows the installation error

Comment: I'll just keep editing my post until this works...

Comment: Yes, I'll run those commands, but for some reason came out these errors: http://paste.laravel.com/iCR

Comment: Not sure why, open an issue and explain exactly what you did because I'm out of ideas here! https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues

Comment: Just a thought, but make sure you have git install `yum install git`